# Как исправить заезд за границу

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Нужно разместить span в левом углу, но происходит вот это (картинка ниже).
Вот код:

HTML

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#clicker{
    background-color: #5C9BC1;
    border: 2px solid #1F648E;
    padding:30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "Roboto";
    color: #1F648E;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <span id="clicker">15</span>

<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Картинка для примера]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавить в стиль #clicker

```
#clicker{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Или играть высотой строки.

Comment: Всё работает! Сяп)